# error while passing data from one activity to other and displaying in a tablelayout

Tags: android, sqlite

hi i am passing the latitude,longitude and address using a bundle to another activity. in another activity i am retrieving data from the bundle. but when i click the button on which bundle is used the app crashes. i cant post the logcat as nothing comes in ddms. i m using the device debug mode. heres my code:

```
                   Bundle b=new Bundle();
                   b.putString("latitude", lat+"");
                   b.putString("longitude", lon+"");
                       b.putString("address", result1);
                   Intent i=new Intent(Cortes.this,Display.class);      
                   i.putExtras(b);
                   startActivity(i)  ;
```

i am writing this in listener of button and Display is the another activity. in that activity my code is:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
latitude=b.getString("latitude");
longitude=b.getString("longitude");
address=b.getString("address");
```

i am displaying db in that activity in a `tablelayout`.
cursor for that i have written in another activity named Display.in cursor i am using the values which i am passing to another activity

pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Bundle b = getIntent.getExtras();
```

or

```
Bundle b = ClassName.this.getIntent.getExtras();
```

Comment: i get a nullpointer exception maybe my db is null. pls tell me how to pass db to another activity

Comment: create the general class which handle the database operation like open, close, fetch etc and creating the object of that class in another classes

Comment: i have created a class that extends sqliteopenhelper and created object of that class in my another activity. pls post the code similar to it or any useful link pls

Comment: i am displaying db in another activity

Answer (score 0):

retrieve data like this:

```
Bundle var_name = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle(key);
```

Comment: i get a nullpointer exception maybe my db is null. pls tell me how to pass db to another activity

Comment: you need not to pass db to another activity .. you can access your db in any activity of your app....how to pass values over activities see this:   http://lovingandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/passing-values-from-one-activity-to.html

Comment: i want to create an object of class which extends sqliteopenhelper in another activity in wich i am displaying db but its returning null pls help how do i get rid of this nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom Bundle, it seems there is some requirements, according to the doc:
`The keys must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".`
The common way I know to share data between activities is to use the default Intent bundle to store them, like this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(Cortes.this,Display.class);      
i.putExtra("latitude", lat+"");
i.putExtra("longitude", lon+"");
i.putExtra("address", result1);
startActivity(i);
```

Then, you retrieve the infos like this:

```
Intent i=this.getIntent();
latitude=i.getStringExtra("latitude");
longitude=i.getStringExtra("longitude");
address=i.getStringExtra("address");
```

Comment: At which line do you have your exception?

Comment: i think my db is null because i dont knw how to pass it to another avctivity pls help me its very urgent pls